# How to capture the result of DOS Commands in C++

Tags: c++, borland-c++

I am creating a windows application that must capture results of several DOS Commands without the command prompt opening and save them into a string. I am using the borland libraries.

`system("dir")` therefore is not good. The result of each command needs to be written to a string variable so I can write it to a log and a separate file.

I have an XML file where they are defined.

The thing i'm struggling on the most is actually capturing the output into a string variable. I have heard of `_popen` but having problems trying to use it.

Comment: Can you show how you tried to use `_popen`, and what the problem was?

Comment: Are we truly talking about **DOS** commands or are you referring to console programs? Look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682499.aspx

Comment: your question is a bit vague but my [small app](http://github.com/iKlsR/pclc) for compiling different libraries quickly *might* be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want is [freopen()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/wk2h68td%28v=vs.80%29) that allows you to redirect the usual streams to a file (either temporary or the separate file you mentioned), and when the process closes, read the file into your log.

I assume the 'result' is the output from the command, and not its return value.